# Bigcommerce plug-in product syncing issues in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bigcommerce

**Error Message**:
[image: Picture-of-error-message]

Here are some information that might be useful.

**WP version**
5.2.5

**Plugins Active**
Akismet Anti-Spam - 4.1.3
BigCommerce for WordPress - 3.12.0
Breadcrumb - 1.5.3
Coming Soon Page, Under Construction & Maintenance Mode by SeedProd - 5.1.0
Contact Form 7 - 5.1.6
Google Maps Easy - 1.9.27
Insert Headers and Footers - 1.4.4
Insert PHP Code Snippet - 1.3.1
Jetpack by WordPress.com - 7.8.1
LiteSpeed Cache - 2.9.9.2
Notification - 6.3.0
SiteOrigin CSS - 1.2.4
Sticky Side Buttons - 1.0.9
UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore - 1.16.20
Yoast SEO - 12.8.1

**Server Environment**
**PHP Version**
7.1.33
**Max Execution Time**
30
**Memory Limit**
256M
**Upload Max Filesize**
256M
**Post Max Size**
8M
**WP debug**
No
**WP debug display**
Yes
**WP debug log**
No
**Mysql Version**
5.5.61
**Web Server**
Apache/2.4.27 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4

**ERROR LOG**

```
[2020-01-17 03:22:27] BigCommerce.INFO: Starting import [] []
[2020-01-17 03:22:28] BigCommerce.INFO: Running import task {"state":"started","description":"Fetching store information"} []
[2020-01-17 03:22:28] BigCommerce.DEBUG: Requesting store settings [] []
[2020-01-17 03:22:30] BigCommerce.DEBUG: Retrieved store settings {"settings":{"bigcommerce_currency_code":"AUD","bigcommerce_currency_symbol":"$","bigcommerce_currency_symbol_position":"left","bigcommerce_decimal_units":2,"bigcommerce_integer_units":4,"bigcommerce_mass_unit":"kg","bigcommerce_length_unit":"cm","bigcommerce_wishlists_enabled":1,"bigcommerce_facebook_pixel_id":"","bigcommerce_google_analytics_id":""}} []
[2020-01-17 03:22:32] BigCommerce.INFO: Running import task {"state":"fetched_store","description":"Retrieving currency settings"} []
[2020-01-17 03:22:32] BigCommerce.DEBUG: Requesting currency settings [] []
[2020-01-17 03:22:35] BigCommerce.INFO: Running import task {"state":"fetched_currencies","description":"Removing Categories"} []
[2020-01-17 03:22:35] BigCommerce.DEBUG: Removing deleted terms for bigcommerce_category taxonomy {"page":1,"limit":50,"taxonomy":"bigcommerce_category"} []
[2020-01-17 03:22:50] BigCommerce.ERROR: API call to https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/zby41x9gmk/v3/catalog/categories?id%3Ain=18%2C19%2C20%2C21%2C22%2C23%2C24%2C25%2C26%2C27%2C28%2C29%2C30%2C31%2C32%2C33%2C34%2C35%2C36%2C37%2C38%2C39%2C40%2C41%2C42%2C43%2C44%2C45%2C46%2C47%2C48%2C49%2C50%2C51%2C52%2C53%2C54%2C55%2C56%2C57%2C58%2C59%2C60%2C61%2C62%2C63%2C64%2C65%2C66%2C67&amp;limit=50&amp;include_fields=id failed: Connection timed out after 15001 milliseconds {"response":null,"headers":null} []
[2020-01-17 03:22:50] BigCommerce.DEBUG: #0 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Api/Caching_Client.php(57): BigCommerce\Api\v3\ApiClient-&gt;callApi('/catalog/catego...', 'GET', Array, '', Array, '\\BigCommerce\\Ap...', '/catalog/catego...') #1 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/vendor/moderntribe/bigcommerce-api-php-v3/src/Api/CatalogApi.php(6469): BigCommerce\Api\Caching_Client-&gt;callApi('/catalog/catego...', 'GET', Array, '', Array, '\\BigCommerce\\Ap...', '/catalog/catego...') #2 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/vendor/moderntribe/bigcommerce-api-php-v3/src/Api/CatalogApi.php(6415): BigCommerce\Api\v3\Api\CatalogApi-&gt;getCategoriesWithHttpInfo(Array) #3 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Import/Processors/Category_Purge.php(30): BigCommerce\Api\v3\Api\CatalogApi-&gt;getCategories(Array) #4 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Import/Processors/Term_Purge.php(74): BigCommerce\Import\Processors\Category_Purge-&gt;get_remote_term_ids(Array) #5 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Container/Import.php(211): BigCommerce\Import\Processors\Term_Purge-&gt;run() #6 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Import/Task_Manager.php(94): BigCommerce\Container\Import-&gt;BigCommerce\Container\{closure}('fetched_currenc...') #7 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Container/Import.php(280): BigCommerce\Import\Task_Manager-&gt;run_next('fetched_currenc...') #8 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): BigCommerce\Container\Import-&gt;BigCommerce\Container\{closure}('fetched_currenc...') #9 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook-&gt;apply_filters(NULL, Array) #10 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook-&gt;do_action(Array) #11 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Import/Runner/Cron_Runner.php(51): do_action('bigcommerce/imp...', 'fetched_currenc...') #12 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Container/Import.php(104): BigCommerce\Import\Runner\Cron_Runner-&gt;continue_import() #13 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(284): BigCommerce\Container\Import-&gt;BigCommerce\Container\{closure}() #14 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook-&gt;apply_filters('', Array) #15 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook-&gt;do_action(Array) #16 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Import/Runner/Cron_Runner.php(73): do_action('bigcommerce_con...') #17 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-content/plugins/bigcommerce/src/BigCommerce/Container/Import.php(108): BigCommerce\Import\Runner\Cron_Runner-&gt;ajax_continue_import() #18 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(284): BigCommerce\Container\Import-&gt;BigCommerce\Container\{closure}() #19 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook-&gt;apply_filters(NULL, Array) #20 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook-&gt;do_action(Array) #21 /home/piranhaoffroadco/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(173): do_action('wp_ajax_bigcomm...') #22 {main} [] []
```

Comment: An API call can timeout for a few reasons. Make sure `https://api.bigcommerce.com` is accessible from the PHP host.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing these logs! To better understand your BC4WP setup I have some follow up questions:

Was the plugin working before and recently stopped working? If so, have there been any updates to other plugins or the theme you're using? If you could share your WordPress site and BigCommerce store URLs, that can also help narrow down what's causing an issue :)

Comment: Yes. It's working before and recently stopped working, then Bigcommerce had an update 5 days ago. I thought the update caused the issue. So I updated the plug-in thinking it would fix the issue but it still persist.

Here's the [Wordpress](http://103.13.103.154/~piranhaoffroadco/) site.
Here's the [Bigcommerce](http://piranhaoffroad.mybigcommerce.com/) store URL.

Here's another problem, the theme that we are using is no longer updated, here's the [link of the theme.](https://wordpress.org/themes/enlightenment/).

I don't know why the first developer used that theme.

Comment: All plug-ins are updated.
The Wordpress version that we're using right now is 5.2.5. The current version of Wordpress is 5.3.2. I'm afraid that if we update the Wordpress itself it will revert all changes that we've made/customize with the theme.

Comment: I would try deactivating and removing the BC4WP plugin, which will remove the products and existing store data from the WordPress site since the error is occurring during imports. From there you can re-install the plugin, activate it using API credentials, and more info can be found on the [dev docs here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/bigcommerce-for-wordpress/setup/multi-site).

Comment: BC4WP is working again 2 days ago BUT the product sync is ultra-slow. Its still syncing until now. I will try what you suggested when its finished syncing. Thanks!